# Changing SharePoint Online New homepage language

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, language, language-pack

I have a customer who has problem with the new SharePoint home page now available in O365 tenants. The SPO language is by default English as they're international company but the language for the new home page is Finnish as company is from Finland.
It doesn't make sense that the UI is otherwise properly in English but this one page is not. It seems the page is getting the language from somewhere else but I've yet to figure out where.

I've tested this out myself with our admin account which has English set as language in SPO user profile as well as in O365 settings. User location is set to Finland but that is pretty much only thing referring to Finnish language.
I suspected that the browser language or OS language would be affecting this but at least on my own tests changing those local settings did not change the language of the SP home.

Has someone else seen this problem and/or have knowledge how this might be solved so that the page would be in English for everybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while figured this out. The language of the root site collection https://tenant.sharepoint.com was Finnish so after changing the language on that site collection the page was switched properly to English.

All the production activity is running on other site collections so the root was left unnoticed initially.